# How do you find the y_axis of a pose bone in specific keyframes in a script?

Tags: animation, scripting, fcurves

How do you find the y_axis of a pose bone in specific keyframes in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Go to the specific frame
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(your_frame)

from mathutils import Vector
# Y-axis in bone's local space
y_axis = Vector((0, 1, 0))
# Y-axis in armature space
y_axis = arma_ob.pose.bones[your_bone_name].matrix @ y_axis
# Y-axis in world space
y_axis = arma_ob.matrix_world @ y_axis
```